# Erro ao tentar rodar aplicação JSF

Tags: java-ee, maven, jboss

Galera estou começando a estudar JBoss, Maven, etc. Porem quando vou executar uma pagina que criei para testes aparece esse erro:

```
Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
```

No meu projeto tenho um diretório chamado Maven Dependencies e dentro dele está o .jar javax.faces-api-2.2.jar Alguem sabe o que pode ser? Obrigado

Comment: primeiramente, você se você está no JBoss, você não pode empacotar junto da sua aplicação qquer jar referente ao JSF pois ele já está disponível dentro do própio JBoss. No maven, coloque o JSF como <scope>provided</scope>, restarte sua aplicação, e diga se o erro continua o mesmo. Seria bom também você editar a pergunta e colocar seu faces-config.xml, pom.xml e web.xml.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, coloquei o <scope>provided</scope> e deu certo. Poste esse comentário como resposta para que eu marque como solução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está no JBoss, você não pode empacotar junto da sua aplicação qualquer jar referente ao JSF pois ele já está disponível dentro do própio JBoss ([Ver neste link recursos disponíveis dentro de um container JEE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html)). No maven, coloque o JSF como provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```